# How to use the value of stdin as the value of a variable that is to be used in an AWK program?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to take the output of one tool, e.g.,

```
echo US59606
```

and use it as the value of an `awk` variable. The variable and its newly assigned value is then used in an `awk` program.

I (incorrectly) thought that this is the way to do it:

```
echo US59606 | awk -v arpt_ident=$1 -f anav_records_for_arpt_ident.awk ANAV.TXT
```

For debugging purposes, in the `awk` program I printed the value of the variable `arpt_ident`. The output I got is the empty string. Bummer.

Question: How to run `awk` with a variable (or variables) whose value(s) come from `stdin`? Here's the general structure of the pipeline that I want `awk` to be a part of:

```
some_cmd | awk -v variable1=??? variable2=??? -f my_program.awk my_file.txt
```

where `some_cmd` produces two values, the first value is to be assigned to `variable1`, the second value is to be assigned to `variable2`. How to assign `variable1` and `variable2` the correct value from `stdin` (the output of `some_cmd`)?

Comment: Is `US59606` a string or a command name? `echo US59606` will just print `US59606`.

Comment: `arpt_ident=$(echo US59606); awk -v arpt_ident=$arpt_ident -f anav_records_for_arpt_ident.awk ANAV.TXT`

Comment: Hello @Jerry Jeremiah what you show works for that specific use case. However, I am interested in the generalize case, where there is command1 whose output is piped into an awk command, and the output from command1 is used as the values of variables in the awk program. Stated another way, the value of stdin becomes the values of awk variables.

Comment: Hello @tshiono US59606 is just a string.

Comment: how would multiple values look if coming from stdin ... all on one line separated by a space (can the values have embedded spaces)? each value on a separate input line? can you guarantee the values will always be in the same order (eg, 1st value will always be assigned to `var1`, 2nd value always assigned to `var2`) or will stdin include some sort of indicator as to which value goes with which variable?

Comment: `xargs` is the canonical command to turn stdin in to arguments. But here you need `var=arg` format which is a bit different.

Comment: Since awk has C-like `ARGV` and `ARGC`, you could use `xargs` and pull arguments directly from `ARGV` array. I sometimes use the environment to quickly pass parameters to awk too (not from stdin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to treat stdin as the 1st file (`FNR==NR`) and have `awk` save the input values either in a pre-defined set of variables or as entries in an array.

A couple variations on using an array based on stdin format ... a) multiple values on a line vs b) each value on a separate line:

```
# values as space-delimited strings on a single line of input:

echo val1 val2 val3 |
awk '
FNR==NR { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              var[i] = $i
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              printf "input: var[%d] = %s\n", i, var[i]
          next }
        { print "do something with 2nd input file" }
' - somefile

# values on separate input lines

printf "val1\nval2\nval3\n" |
awk '
FNR==NR { var[++c]=$0
          next
        }
FNR==1  { for (i=1;i<=c;i++)
              printf "input: var[%d] = %s\n", i, var[i]
        }
        { print "do something with 2nd input file" }
' - somefile
```

Where:

- `- inputfile` says to take stdin (`-`) as the 1st input file and `somefile` as the 2nd input file
- by processing stdin as a 'file' we eliminate the need for command line `-v var=val` clauses
- the `awk` script would then reference the array entries instead of the variables (eg, replace `arpt_ident` with `var[1]`)

Both of these generate:

```
input: var[1] = val1
input: var[2] = val2
input: var[3] = val3
do something with 2nd input file
do something with 2nd input file
do something with 2nd input file
do something with 2nd input file
... snip ...
```

---

Of if individual variable names are required:

```
echo val1 val2 val3 |
awk '
FNR==NR { arpt_ident=$1
          id=$2
          var3=$3
        }
... snip ...
' - somefile

printf "val1\nval2\nval3\n" |
awk '
FNR==NR { if (FNR==1) arpt_ident=$1          # alternatively look at using "switch" (aka awk case statement)
          if (FNR==2) id=$2
          if (FNR==3) var3=$3
        }
... snip ...
' - somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

For a file like bellow

```
cat file1
1 line0
2 line1
3 line2
4 line3
```

Something like this will use the stdin to filter the file:

```
echo "line2" |awk -v awkvar="$(</dev/stdin)" '$2 ~ awkvar {print}' file1
3 line2
```

Answer (score 0):

If `some_cmd` would produce only a single "value" (i.e. you want to pass the whole stdout of the command to a variable in awk), you can do a

```
awk -v var1="$(some_cmd)" ....
```

If it produces two values,as in your question, you must first make up your mind, how these values are stored in the standard output. Let's assume that there are two **words** in the bash sense of *word splitting*. In this case, it is easiest to use an auxiliary bash array:

```
cmd_output=( $(some_cmd) )
awk -v var1=${cmd_output[0]} -v var2=${cmd_output[1]} ....
```

If the output of your command is more complex, you need to parse it somehow. For instance to extract the first two integers from the output, you could do a

```
if [[ $(some_cmd) =~ (-?[[:digit:]]+).*(-?[[:digit:]]+) ]]
then
  awk -v var1="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" -v var2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ...
```

Depending on your parsing requirements, you may find it easier to do the parsing completely inside awk. In this case, you would pass the whole standard output to a single awk variable and inside the `BEGIN` block of your awk program calculate the variables which are needed later.